# How does s3fs work behind the scenes?

Tags: s3fs

Does s3fs make range requests default 10mb size for each file ?Also I trained a model using data from s3fs so the time compared to ebs increased linearly with the no of epoch.Why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

By default s3fs does issue range requests.  You can observe this by running `s3fs -f -o curldbg` which emits the HTTP requests and responses.  Sample output for a 40MB file:

```
> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=131072-10616831

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Content-Range: bytes 131072-10616831/40776154

> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=10616832-21102591

> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=31588352-40776153

> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=21102592-31588351

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Content-Range: bytes 21102592-31588351/40776154

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Content-Range: bytes 31588352-40776153/40776154

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Content-Range: bytes 10616832-21102591/40776154

> GET /filename HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-131071

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Content-Range: bytes 0-131071/40776154
```

Note that requests are issued out of order.

s3fs may be slower than EBS for your use case; s3fs works well for bulk data transfer but not for random access.